# Loading URL into ng-view programatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view

Referring to the code given below, I would like to be able to load `viewTeam` URL into `ng-view` from the `showTeam()` function. How can I do this?

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var teamApp = angular.module("teamApp", ['ngRoute']);

        teamApp.controller('teamController', function($scope, $http) {

            $http
                    .get('/teams')
                    .success(function(response) {
                        $scope.teams = response;
                    }
                    );


            var showTeam = function(id) {

            }
        });

        teamApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.

            when('/addTeam', {
                templateUrl: 'addTeam.htm',
                controller: 'AddTeamController'
            }).

            when('/viewTeam', {
                templateUrl: 'viewTeam.htm',
                controller: 'ViewTeamController'
            }).

            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/addTeam'
            });
        }]);

        teamApp.controller('AddTeamController', function($scope) {

        });

        teamApp.controller('ViewTeamController', function($scope, $routeParams) {

        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-app = "teamApp" ng-controller="teamController">

    <button ng-click="newTeam()">new</button>

    <div ng-repeat="team in teams" >
        Name: {{team.name}}
        <br />
        Description: {{team.description}}
        <br />
        <button ng-click="showTeam(team.id)">show</button>
    </div>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "addTeam.htm">
        <h2> Add Team </h2>
        To be implemented later.
    </script>

    <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "viewTeam.htm">
        Name: {{team.name}}
        Description: {{team.description}}
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your **$routeprovider** for viewTeam to expect an id parameter. Then get that id in the viewTeamController using **routeparams**. Here is how you do it. Just follow the pattern in the `script` below:

```
<script>
            var teamApp = angular.module("teamApp", ['ngRoute']);

            teamApp.controller('teamController', function($scope, $http,$location) {

                $http
                        .get('/teams')
                        .success(function(response) {
                            $scope.teams = response;
                        }
                        );


                var showTeam = function(id) {
               $location.url("#/viewTeam/" + id);//there are other means as well.
                }
            });

            teamApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.

                when('/addTeam', {
                    templateUrl: 'addTeam.htm',
                    controller: 'AddTeamController'
                }).

                when('/viewTeam/:id', {
                    templateUrl: 'viewTeam.htm',
                    controller: 'ViewTeamController'
                }).

                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/addTeam'
                });
            }]);

            teamApp.controller('AddTeamController', function($scope) {

            });

            teamApp.controller('ViewTeamController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
            alert($routeParams.id);//you get the route params here.
            });
    </script>
```

When navigating from view:

```
 <a href="#viewTeam/45">
```

In your case:

```
<a href="#viewTeam/{{team.id}}"> //to navigate from view.
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Your answer led me to the solution.

Comment: I am glad i could be of help to you :)

Answer (score 1):

In your **teamController** do this -

```
var showTeam = function(id) {
    $location.path('/viewTeam.htm').search({'id': id});
}
```

In **ViewTeamController** you can get id like this

```
//Get id from url params
$location.search('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$location` to change the path

```
    $scope.showTeam = function(view){
        $location.path("/viewTeam"); // path not hash
    }
```